# Prevent page refresh on pressing F5

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I have Created form with Server Side control like button..and also have written event on that..
Now runtime after click on the button i have refreshed the page by pressing F5.Page_load is executing fine but button1_click() event also firing...So how can i stop this event execution in this scenario.Please suggest me

Comment: I am no Web programmer, but I give it a try to brainstorming. Would it not be a story about a PostBack or the like? Would it work if you verify whether it's a PostBack, etc?

Answer (score 11):

Short Answer: Not possible

Longer Answer: No web site can block the browser's functionality as that would be a serious security concern for the browser.

Comment: hi...Joel..cureently when i saved a record... i am  displaying a sucess message in same page. And if  irefresh the page (ctrl + F5) or F5..one more record is getting inserted. so, with the same details tworecords are inserted. I ned to prevent inserting duplicate records.

Comment: The way around that use case is to post to a different URL, process, and then redirect back to the first page with the success or error message in the querystring. Unfortunately, the post-back model of ASP.NET makes this next to impossible. All you can do is redirect after you successfully process to a "thank you" style page (which is completely separate from the first page). That way, if the user refreshes that, it won't resubmit. In essence, you must never display the result in the same response as the post which initiated the action.

Comment: Also, do some research into Idempotency. You need to make your actions idempotent :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to web development, there is no way to stop the page from refreshing and reposting, this is entirely a browser behavior.

There are work arounds though; one simple thing that you can do is after processing your button click, you can redirect the browser *back* to the page so that a refresh will not include a repost of your button press.  Obviously this might require some other state management system (rather than view-state), maybe you can store your state in the Session.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function checkKeyCode(evt)// for F5 disable
    {

        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
        if (event.keyCode == 116)//disable F5
        {
            evt.keyCode = 0;
            return false
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            evt.keyCode = 0;
            return false
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 93) {
            evt.keyCode = 0;
            return false
        }
        if (event.altKey == true && event.keyCode == 115) //disable alt-F4
        {
            evt.keyCode = 0;
            return false
        }



        //alert(event.keyCode);
    }

    document.onkeydown = checkKeyCode;

</script>
```

Post this script on your master page or where u want to block F5 button.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function ()
{
    return false;
}
```

This will display a prompt asking the user if they want to navigate away and may not be desired. (Plus, I don't know the extent of support)

Answer (score 2):

The poster is using ASP.NET WebForms.  In MVC, using the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, this would not be a problem.

But this has been solved for Webforms since 2004 (and even before that - I wrote a simple ticket solution in 2001) with this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379557.aspx

Basically the author creates a unique ticket associated with each request, and removes the validity of the ticket on first postback.  Any accidental (or malicious) subsequent postbacks are ignored.  It's wrapped up in a base page so it should be easy to add to any Webforms solution.

Answer (score 1):

Its not really page refresh that you want to block, its page re-`POST`.

As already said, it's not possible on the client side because the refresh will replay what the browser did on the last action.

But you can trap it on the server side because the server can hold some infos to control the request.

The easiest way is to put a sort of *RequestID* in a hidden field on `Page Load`, store it somewhere like in the `Session`. And control its value on next `POST` to valid the request then override it to avoid re-`POST` with the same *RequestID*.

Maybe there's a better way :)

Your 'problem' is similar to a user double-click horror behavior : [ASP.Net double-click problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498269/asp-net-double-click-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to refresh the page on the click of the button? Could you rewire the button to make an ajax call to submit the data? If so, then you would not need to worry about the page re-submitting on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for the F5 refresh problem is `Response.Redirect`. Please see my post on this topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596152/asp-net-f5-browser-refresh-duplicate-record/12596153#12596153

Answer (score 0):

I got some code that doesn't allow you to press F5 and/or Ctrl + R:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Key code test!
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x, ctrlKeyPressed = false;  
function keyDown(e){            
x = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = x;
if(x == 17) {
ctrlKeyPressed = true;
}
if(ctrlKeyPressed && x == 82) {
e.preventDefault();
} else if(x == 116) {
e.preventDefault();
}
}
function keyUp(e) {
x = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
if(x == 17) {
ctrlKeyPressed = false;
}
}
window.onload = function () {
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
keyDown(e);
};
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
keyUp(e);
};
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Press a key!
<br/>
Key code: <div style="display:inline;" id="key">Nothing</div>
</body>
</html>
```